# Change SeekBar position using TextView in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, seekbar

I want to change the position of a seekbar according to a textview. I am making a prediction app in which I am using a seekbar and when I change the seekbar position the TextView value is changing. I am storing this value in SQLite and when I rerun the app the last prediction shows on the TextView but the seekbar position remains constant. How can I change the position of the seekbar according to the TextView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
seekBar.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(textView.getText().toString()));
```

Answer (score 0):

To initalize seek bar dynamically, first get the value from text view and set it to the sek bar progress. Like:-

```
val progress = textView.text.toString().toInt()
seekBar.setProgress(progress)
```

or else you can directly set the value whatever you are getting from SQlite to seek bar progress after converting it to Int if data is not Int type.